# Does Firebase Storage cache getData requests when offline?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I understood Firebase Storage not to have offline capability (because of open git requests for the feature and no mention of it in documentation) but I appear to observe it. When the client is offline and I attempt to get data from Storage, the return closure is expectedly not called. However, when the client comes back online, that closure is immediately called (returning the file from Storage), which appears to suggest that the request to get data was cached when the client was offline. Is this indeed the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no caching, but the SDK will retry with the hopes that a future request will succeed.

Comment: I assume Storage will eventually give up retrying and if the device comes back online after that point, the closure won't return on its own, correct?

Comment: Eventually.  The code for each platforms's SDK is open source, so you can see exactly what it does.